# I want external links to open in my browser

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to external link to open within my app not ask me to open them in Google Chrome or the standard Internet app. Like when I click a link I want my browser app to set it to default or use it just once. Thanks! I code in Android Studio.

Comment: Do you mean when third party apps open links, you want them to open your browser instead of prompting?

Comment: Hi Chaos, you should read this tutorial on the android developer website about app links: http://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Comment: @DeeV yes sir that's exactly what I want..

Comment: @SammyJaafar Ok sir thanks..

Comment: @DeeV I get that sir but I want my app to be among them like to ask me if I want to open it in Google Chrome, Opera... etc. or my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the intent filter for your app, if your app has link opening functionality. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) guide should be helpful for you.